# How to query two consecutive "criteria rows" with DGET in Excel?

Tags: database, excel, row, criteria

[image: DB QUERY]
where DB.VALORI function is DGET in english.

For the queries, the rule is that the criteria row must be under the label row.
The query 1 is ok, is there a way to add query 2?

Comment: =INDEX(D:D,MATCH(G2&H2&I2,A:A&B:B&C:C,0)) is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I personally don't use this `DGET` function but someone can probably help you here.  This is another way you can try with an **array formula** (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together):

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$5,MATCH(G2&H2&I2,$A$2:$A$5&$B$2:$B$5&$C$2:$C$5,0))
```

This can do multiple matches and find the result you want.  Give it a shot and let me know if you have any question.

P.S.  You will need to translate the formula function to your language and doesn't forget to change `,` to `;` in the formula.